# Overlay and copy picture over other picture

Tags: html, css

I have this picture:

[image]

and I want this picture:

[image]

to be over the picture so I get this "dot-effect".

I also have to repeat the picture so it fits the other one. I managed to have them both in the same place but never to have the second one repeated over the first one.

Please help. I googled this for the past 2 days and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this dynamically in HTML/CSS? If this is an image you simply need to produce once why not use an image editor (i.e. photoshop)?  -- also, you need to show up what you have tried so far code-wise.

Comment: If you have just simple-color background, consider creating a transparent image (background with "cut off" silhouette)

Comment: yes i know i could easily get the effect in photoshop. but to answer your question: yes i want this with just html and css. I saw a similar thing a few months ago on a website (i just don't rember the site anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple background images

```css
.avatar {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9pqm.png), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSToa.png);
  background-repeat: repeat, none;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar"></div>
```

or alternatively, an actual image in the HTML and a pseudo-element overlay.

```css
.avatar {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
}
.avatar::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9pqm.png) repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSToa.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use first image as main background, than use `position: absolute` and background image on another element to place doted image over first one. Why background image for overlay? It's because you can set `background-repeat` attribute for background (default to repeat x and y).

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9pqm.png") repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSToa.png" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2592686 If answer satisfies you, please accept answer.

Comment: Sorry but an other one was better.. your solution kind of messed the hole layout up.. Idk why..